# Javascript automation to search data through webpages

Tags: javascript, automation

I have a list of URLs that I have to enter and get information from HTML and format the content in a way to post it like in an social app. I've already automated with a JScript how to get the information and organize but is still not fast enough since I have to go in each link and run in the console of the browser so then it saves me a file with the data.

What I'm looking for is how to make a 'foreach' going all those URLs and running the script I already have. Can this be done solely with JS? What would be a good way to handle that?

Comment: please add your code  for someone to be able to answer

Comment: I'll could post my code, but I think it's not a code related problem, the code I have works well getting information out of a webpage. my problem is how to execute this JavaScript code I have multiple times in a list of URL's

Comment: set up selenium with Java. then use `Set <String> allTabs = driver.getWindowHandles();
   allTabs.remove(baseTab);
   Iterator<String> itr = allTabs.iterator();
   while(itr.hasNext()){
     newTab = (String) itr.next();
    }` to open tabs . With in each tab you open each of your URL one by one by putting some iterator on those URLs  and then use `executeScript` to run your JS within selenium. [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) is the `executeScript` class

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899094/how-to-open-multiple-tab-in-the-same-browser) is the link for multiple tabs. Let us know if it helps, I can add this as answer.